# How to check two fields in a table while insert or update in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

How to check two fields in a table while insert or update in SQLite

TableName = SUBJECT

Fields = SRNO, SEM, SUBID, SUBNAME, LEC, LAB

SRNO is a Primary key

if same SEM and SUBID is exist in table then query should replace only the old values with newer values of SUBNAME, LEC, LAB fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `SEM`/`SUBID` are a candidate key, you should let the database check this with a unique constraint/index.

When you have a unique constraint, you can use the INSERT OR REPLACE statement, which replaces the row if inserting would result in a constraint violation:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Subject(SRNO, SEM, SUBID, SUBNAME, LEC, LAB) VALUES(...)
```

Please note that REPLACE does not update the row in place, but just deletes the old row and then insert a new row with the new values.
If you have some column(s) whose old value(s) you want to keep, you have to code the INSERT/UPDATEs by hand.